# Why is my DSLR screen showing an image settings tab while viewing other images?

Tags: dslr, nikon-d5600

When I press the play button to view previously clicked pictures, the screen pops up an image settings tab with the image in the background. This tab does not disappear until I zoom in the image.

The attached picture shows the above mentioned issue.

Has this happened to anyone before? What do I need to do?
[image]

Comment: Is this a new behavior or has it always done this ? do you have the manual ? Have you tried to find the manual online and learn how to set the controls of your camera ?

Comment: This is a new behavior. Let me check for the manual.

Comment: You should say what model of camera this applies to.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong. When seeing the playback of your images use the up and down keys to get different views with different information being displayed. Just keep pressing up or down until the camera just shows only the image.

Comment: But it did not appear before. Not sure why the issue is persistent now.

Comment: That is no issue at all. It is a normal behavior. I always press multiple times up or down when checking my images to view the histogram and then pressing the up button again to only have the image displayed. You might accidentally have pressed the up or down button when you pressed left or right to scroll through the images. You press the gallery button to view your images and keep pressing up to make it disappear.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, there is nothing *wrong* with this. You must have either recently chosen to access this information, or never spotted that the up/down buttons on the image playback rotate around the different view options you have set in the menu.

It surprised me the first time, when I was new - "Why do I suddenly have a histogram taking up most of the space & just a teeny picture?"

Menu button > Playback menu [first icon] > Playback Display options. Check or uncheck as you wish. These are the ones you will be able to step through with the up/down buttons in playback view. The one you have in the image is Shooting Data, which is itself about 3 pages of up/down button.

Personally, I find the useful ones to be none, histogram & overview. That leaves you actually with 4 pages, as you can't switch the default off, a pretty useless one with a tiny overlay ay the bottom, then a full histogram showing each colour separately, lastly the more important details of the shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can change what information is displayed with each image by using the 'Up' and 'Down' Keys on the 'Multi Selector' dial on the back of the camera.

[image]

It's all covered on pages 184 and 188 of the [*Nikon D5600 Reference Manual*](https://www.lensrentals.com/product-assets/ccc18a91-2f71-4233-b3fa-eacf0b1a0628/D5600%20reference%20manual.pdf)

[image: p.184]

[image: p.188]

For how to select which photo information views are included as you cycle through them using the Up/Down buttons, please see page 221 of the [*Nikon D5600 Reference Manual*](https://www.lensrentals.com/product-assets/ccc18a91-2f71-4233-b3fa-eacf0b1a0628/D5600%20reference%20manual.pdf)